# How to blur images and videos in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I blur images and videos in google chrome and to manage the websites that will be affected from this extenstion?
I saw this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blur-the-image-and-video/aikjogmpaoaookmacnkbenekcnkjlkmi/related

But there is only two options in this extension: TURN ON or TURN OFF (to all the websites, but I want to be able to decide which sites not to run it on ("white list")).

Someone meet some extension that can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

This extension blurs images and videos on sites that exclude exclude_matches.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "exclude_matches": ["*://hoge.com/*"],
      "css": [
        "matches.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.css

```
img, video {
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

Comment: What I need to do with that? can you add explain about that ? Where should i add it ?

Comment: I thought you were asking how to make an extension. Were you looking for an extension someone made?

Comment: Yes. but if you can explain me how to make an extension (if it's simple and don't need a lot time, so it's also ok)..

Comment: I have it on my homepage.